# How to use DATE command with an external variable?

Tags: bash, time

I'm working on a time convertion script. It is supposed to do something like this:

```
echo $(( ($(date -d '00:10:2.00' +%s) - $(date -d 0 +%s) ) ))
```

This line is working just fine giving me the result

```
602
```

But I want to put the the first part of the date string (`00:10:2.00`) under a) an command line argument so it could be read from `$1` like:

```
echo $(( ($(date -d '$1' +%s) - $(date -d 0 +%s) ) ))
```

OR as a variable:

```
echo $(( ($(date -d '$myvariable' +%s) - $(date -d 0 +%s) ) ))
```

When I'm trying this:

```
foo="00:10:2.00"
echo $foo
echo $(( ($(date -d '$foo' +%s) - $(date -d 0 +%s) ) ))
```

All I get is:

```
00:10:2.00
date: invalid date `$foo'
-1417042800
```

So it's echoing properly but it aint working with the time command...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, they're not expanded inside single quotes. So use

```
date -d "$1" +%s
```

Comment: I should've tried this before using Stackoverflow precious resources to ask this stupid question... Thanks! ;)